# index.php not getting blog posts anymore

Tags: posts

I'm working on a WordPress website that I set up a few years ago and I've noticed that the /blog page is not longer displaying posts. I'm assuming that something changed and broke in an update, but I can't find any information.

This is my loop in index.php:

```
<div id="blog" class="container blog test">
    <div class="row">
        <main class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <header class="post-byline">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="section-heading"><?php the_title() ;?></h2></a>
                        <p><span class="post-time"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-o"></i> <?php get_the_time('M jS, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('G:i T'); ?></span> <span class="post-tags"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-tags"></i> <?php the_tags('', ', ', ''); ?></span> <span class="post-comments"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments-o"></i> <a href="#comments" class="page-scroll"><fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count> comments</a></span></p>
                    </header>

                    <div class="post-thumb">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </article>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p>Sorry, this post does not exist.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>

        </main>
        <?php get_sidebar() ;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only one entry renders with a random date that doesn't correspond to any of my posts and `h2.section-heading` is simply "Blog". The same functions still work on the homepage, so I imagine this page isn't referencing something correctly?

Comment: Is the page set as the posts page in _Settings > Reading_?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I think you're on to something. I haven't played with these settings before, but it was set to "Your homepage displays - Your latest posts". If I manually set homepage to "Home" and "Posts page" to "Blog", my homepage gets replaced with /blog, but it displays posts like it should, just on the wrong page. Not sure why the templates are getting mixed up like this